# Sending SMS using SMS Modem and Phpserial Class

Tags: php, serial-port, sms, gsm, at-command

I'm using a device like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=GPRS+Modem&sxsrf=ACYBGNSaamI0HqEjZrM-ew59nRYv5lctEQ:1580550102344&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt8Jj7h7DnAhWwUN4KHebwDy0Q_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1536&bih=754

I want to send an SMS message using Phpserial class, I've already searched and followed some instructions on how to implement it. To make sure, I've downloaded an AT Tester to try sending message from my phone to my device and it was successful.

Now I want to implement it in PHP and I tried using Phpserial class. I am using windows OS and when I tried it, it returns no error but I didn't received any message. I tried to check console and network, it has no response and it returns no error i think?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    require('PhpSerial.php');

    $num_send = $_POST['number'];
    $txt = $_POST['txt_msg'];      

    $serial = new PhpSerial;

    if($serial->deviceSet("COM4")){
        $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
        $serial->confParity("none");
        $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
        $serial->confStopBits(1);
        $serial->confFlowControl("none");
        if($serial->deviceOpen()){
            $serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=1\n\r"); 
            $serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgs=\"".$num_send."\"\n\r");
            $serial->sendMessage(" ".$txt." \n\r");

        $serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

        //wait for modem to send message
        sleep(7);
        $read=$serial->readPort();
        $serial->deviceClose();
        echo "Success";
        }
    }        
?>
```

The code above has no errors but I didn't received any message. Why ?

Comment: And how PC is supposed to send an SMS message from a serial port? According to an [article](https://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) you can send SMS only from a phone that’s connected to PC, or an SMS gateway. I assume you used the first through connecting the phone via serial cable - then the question is what you have received back from calling sendMessage for each time?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov im using this device https://www.google.com/search?q=gprs+modem&sxsrf=ACYBGNS4Mh6Ku1UTkzFQwGJStDchgh4DWQ:1580548560768&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=InwlIn1oFU5ueM%253A%252CGpmiXywXg2wWvM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kSwtritOwyAUoNDCHMKJKMoP3dtTw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi67Y6cgrDnAhWLHHAKHb1BCXwQ9QEwAHoECAgQJg#imgrc=InwlIn1oFU5ueM:

Comment: Showing us the actual traffic sniffed from the AT port would be helpful. I mean both commands sent an received responses.

Comment: So do you confirm that with the AT tester you correctly received the SMS? In this case it can only be caused by an error in the program (for example: the destination number is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If use AT-Tester and success send,
You need the accepted command and Characters from GPRS device
best way sniff transfer packet from AT-Tester to GPRS Modem. [Serial Port Monitor](https://www.com-port-monitoring.com/) or [freeserialanalyzer.com](http://freeserialanalyzer.com) Free Best tools for detect the accepted command and Characters. Only generate liked packet monitored.

Comment: My code echoing success, but i didn't received the text message. Is there something wrong? or compatibility of the device ?

Comment: The send packet from code and AT-Tester is equal? please checked char by char.

Comment: i tried to download the Serial Port Monitor, but if i will start logging it, my PHP Code will return Warning: Specified serial port is not valid in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms_test\PhpSerial.php on line 120. If i will turn off the logger, it will return success. I think its conflicting my COM4 port ?

Comment: Can remote me from AnyDesc for checking?

Comment: also i tried to run AT Tester and same result if i will turn on the Serial Port Monitor, it says Found ports :COM4

COM4  is currently in use. Please close the application that is using this port and connect again.